# Django get rid of duplicated queries in nested models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have models as shown below,

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    
    @property
    def latest_variant(self):
        return self.carvariant_set.last()

class CarVariant(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

and I am making a query to get the latest variant of all cars, I am getting much duplicated queries.
I couldn't eliminate it with `prefetch_related`

```
Car.objects.all().prefetch_related('carvariant_set')
```

How can I eliminate the duplicated queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `.prefetch_related` it will populate the `carvariant_set` value, but only for a `.all()` query, not for a `.last()`, that will trigger a new query.

What we can do is define a property like:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    
    @property
    def latest_variant(self):
        items = getattr(self, '_latest_variants', ())
        if items:
            return items[-1]
        return self.carvariant_set.last()
```

Then we can prefetch the related object with:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

Car.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'carvariant_set',
        queryset=CarVariant.objects.order_by('pk'),
        to_attr='_latest_variants'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of duplicates you use "distinct()".
For example Car.objects.all().prefetch_related('carvariant_set').distinct(). You can read about it here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

sometimes you might need to tell the "distinct" function which fields make an object distinct. By default it's the id, but you can do something like "distinct('name')" in order to avoid getting 2 instances with the same name for example.

Comment: its not about the duplicated results but with the duplicated queries.